# Can I update / delete / insert database records via power query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mysql, power-query, mariadb

So I use *Get & Transform* (fka *Power Query*) in Office 365 / Excel 365 to query a MariaDB database (equivalent to MySQL in this case).

Given that I have the database permissions to do so, can I edit the data source from within Excel?

It does not seem so, but I rather ask then miss an opportunity!

Comment: Using SQL Server it's possible,, unfortunately no idea about MariaDB !!

Comment: So how would you do it? Just load a table, edit some data an hit "Save" or "Push"? I mean, where are the buttons?

Comment: No,, just  by using the `Update Query`,, and others.

Answer (score 0):

I found this

https://querypower.com/2017/04/04/exporting-power-query-tables-to-sql-server/

Please try and give a response if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Power Update has a "no-code" export to SQL Server. Perhaps MariaDB could import from there?

https://poweronbi.com/power-update/

Answer (score -1):

You might also look at https://www.acterys.com they offer a variety of write back features including Power BI visuals and an Excel Add-in